# Dúvida pré-desenvolvimento sobre app android com sincronização de dados

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, apk

Gostaria de fazer um aplicativo simples de cadastro de usuários utilizando java.

Porém essa aplicação deve manter um banco de dados local para acesso dos dados offline e um banco de dados na nuvem para sincronizar as informações quando eu clicar em um botão "sincronizar".

A minha dúvida é que bancos de dados eu posso utilizar para a nuvem e para o armazenamento local.

Tenho esse tipo de dúvida pois ainda não me aventurei com desenvolvimento em java e nem desenvolvimento para Android e a intenção é utilizar algo que seja de mais fácil implementação, ou que já seja um padrão para esse tipo de aplicação.

Answer (score 2):

Para a utilização do Banco de dados interno, sugiro que utilize o `SQLite`. O Android tem suporte nativo para ele, e é super tranquilo de implementar.

Para a sincronização na nuvem, caso não queira desenvolver uma API para isto, sugiro que utilize alguma ferramenta como o `Parse Core`. Essa ferramenta permite que salve informações na nuvem sem a necessidade de uma API. Eles possuem um SDK para o Android que é super simples e tem uma documentacao bem completa de utilizacao

- **SQLite**: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html
- **Parse**: https://parse.com/products/core e https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects

Comment: Desculpe, ainda não entendi muito bem. Esse Parse Core seria para facilitar uma sincronização? Mas o banco de dados a ser utilizado seria qual?

Comment: Você não precisa se preocupar com banco de dados ou escabilidade! Dê uma lida no site que você irá entender como funciona. Caso não entender, edito minha resposta com algumas explicacoes

Comment: Eu vi o site, só não sei se entendi direito pq pelo que entendi os dados ficam no próprio servidor do Parse. Eu estava pensando em gravar os dados num banco próprio de uma hospedagem minha. MySql por exemplo.